# Creating azure storage account by C#

Tags: c#, azure

I have an azure subscription and wants to create a azure storage account by Asp.net C#.
Anyone has Idea? I did a lot research but couldnt find any relevant sample.

Comment: that probably took me 45 seconds - https://thuru.net/2014/10/06/how-to-create-azure-storage-account-programmatically-net-sdk/

Comment: I saw that link but I don like to use certificate file, other way with complitly hard coding

Comment: Actually that is an old API and is not recommended anymore.. I have posted a sample with the latest API.

Comment: I dont have Active directory, how can I connect to my subscription without active directory?

Comment: You should specify your unwillingness of using a certificate or configuring an AD in the question.

Comment: You want to perform actions without authentication? That's an unreasonable request

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<StorageAccount> CreateStorageAccountAsync(
  TokenCredentials credential,       
  string groupName,
  string subscriptionId,
  string location,
  string storageName)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Creating the storage account...");
  var storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(credential)
    { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
  return await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(
    groupName,
    storageName,
    new StorageAccountCreateParameters()
    {
      Sku = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku() 
        { Name = SkuName.StandardLRS},
      Kind = Kind.Storage,
      Location = location
    }
  );
}
```

See the source for setup steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-csharp

Comment: This requires a configured AD as well, and OP is looking for a way without using an AD or certificate.

Comment: Yes, he\she didn't mention it until only after I posted the answer. Anyway you obviously can't perform actions without authenticating first.